# SSIS VS17 Unsupported: This version of visual studio is unable to open the following projects .dtproj

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I get this error when trying to open VS17 With SSIS Project written on VS15:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These actions solved my problem:

- Install the [latest version of SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)
- Open Visual Studio 2017: Go to: Tools > Extensions And Updates > Search: Microsoft Integration Services Projects > Click: Enable
- Restart Visual Studio
- In SSIS Project On Solution: Right Click > Reload Project

Comment: Strange,  I didn't upgrade and VS 2017 would not open this project of SSIS that I created with VS 2017.   Sure enough it was not enabled.   How annoying  :/    thx this worked. ( I didn't need to install latest version of SSDT )

Comment: Analysis and Reporting Services are not required according to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25361/visual-studio-is-unable-to-open-dtproj-projects-in.html)